# Orchard part doesn't save

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

Walking through [this](http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-4) tutorial everything is fine but the data doesn't save.
Tables has been created and edit page shows the fields but no record has been saved. After clicking the save button I get this message:

> Your Car ContentType has been created.
>
> Not found
>
> The page you are looking for does not exist.

Any idea?

Models:

```
public class CarPart : ContentPart<CarPartRecord> {
    public string Name {
        get { return Record.Name; }
        set { Record.Name = value; }
    }
    public string Description {
        get { return Record.Description; }
        set { Record.Description = value; }
    }
    public bool IsPublished {
        get { return Record.IsPublished; }
        set { Record.IsPublished = value; }
    }
}
public class CarPartRecord : ContentPartRecord {
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsPublished { get; set; }
}
```

Handlers:

```
public class CarPartHandler : ContentHandler {
    public CarPartHandler(IRepository<CarPartRecord> repository) {
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
    }
}
```

Drivers:

```
public class CarPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<CarPart> {
    protected override string Prefix { get { return "Car"; } }
    protected override DriverResult Editor(CarPart part, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        return ContentShape("Parts_Car_Edit", () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: "Parts/Car", Model: part, Prefix: Prefix));
    }
    protected override DriverResult Editor(CarPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }
}
```

Migrations:

```
public int Create(){
        SchemaBuilder.DropTable("CarPartRecord");
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("CarPartRecord", table => table
            .ContentPartRecord()
            .Column<string>("Name",column => column.WithLength(50).NotNull().Unique())
            .Column<string>("Description",column => column.WithLength(500))
            .Column<bool>("IsPublished",column => column.WithDefault(true).NotNull()));
        return 1;
    }
    public int UpdateFrom1() {
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("CarPart",part => part.Attachable());
        return 2;
    }
```

Errors:

Orchard.Exceptions.DefaultExceptionPolicy - Default - An unexpected exception was caught
 http...../OrchardLocal/Admin/Contents/Create/Car
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute batch command.[SQL: SQL not available] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Name', table 'OrchardDB.dbo.Mega_Car_CarPartRecord'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

NHibernate.AssertionFailure - Default - An AssertionFailure occurred - this may indicate a bug in NHibernate or in your custom types.
 http..../OrchardLocal/Admin/Contents/Create/Car
NHibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentTypeRecord entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Orchard.Web\Modules\M.Car\Views\EditorTemplates\Parts

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@model  M.Car.Models.CarPart
<fieldset>
    <legend>Car Fields</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Description)</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Description)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.IsPublished)</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.IsPublished)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.IsPublished)
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Please also show your migration, and look for exceptions in your logs.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I just updated it with migrations and error. And 'Name' has been filled in UI.

Comment: Your driver seems to be lacking all forms of validation, but the issue is probably in your editor template. Please also show that.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy and here is the view!

Comment: Did you try to attach a debugger and break into the Editor method?

Comment: Thank you @BertrandLeRoy. It seems that the problem was because of web.config files that I copied from the tutorial into my project which were for older version of .Net and not compatible with my project.